# Angular.JS 1.4 $injector:module error when trying to include NgSanitize in my app

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I have been looking at solutions online and on this site but couldn't figure out why when adding 'ngSanitize' to my controller I get the injector-module error in my app.

https://jsfiddle.net/mxmqxos7/2/

```
    angular.module('mainapp', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('FormController', ['$scope','$sce' function($scope, $sce) {

         $scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<label>test123</label>');

        }]);
```

If you need any more details let me know and I will provide. I have included the right CDNs on the fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't have anything at all to do with angular.  The problem is with jsfiddle.net and the order that it loads scripts.  Since it loads scripts  (`onload`) before resources by default, angular isn't loaded when the script is run.  You need to change the script to load as `No Wrap - in <head>` instead.

Comment: @Claies But this is a problem in my code as well....How can I reproduce it without jsfiddle

Comment: Fixing the typo and changing the load order fixes the example fiddle you provided.  If the typo isn't the problem in your code, then you need to provide an up to date example.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after $sce in your controller array.

Change the JSFiddle Load-type to no wrap in head and it works.

Comment: Same error, doesn't change anything but thanks for noticing. I updated the code. https://jsfiddle.net/mxmqxos7/2/

Answer (score 0):

This work: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbBGKBOXRedN6NpboscU?p=preview

```
   var app = angular.module('mainapp', ['ngSanitize']);

   app.controller('FormController', function($scope, $sce) {

   $scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<label>test123</label>');

   });
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to recognize your quality up